# ReactJs onClick on mobile phones

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJs and trying to create a simple menu bar.
My menu is working on my laptop, but on mobile it doesn't change the active menu color.
If I place a menu item directly in the render(), it's working (see "WORKING" menu item), but my original idea doesn't change the menu background on mobiles.
I have no idea why.
Thank you for reading.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './menu-main.sass';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
}   from "react-router-dom";

const MenuButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <li className={props.className} onClick={props.onClick}>
            <Link to={'/' + props.route}>{props.name}</Link>
        </li>
    );
}

const menus = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Products', route: 'products'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Categories', route: 'category'},
    {id: 2, name: 'About', route: 'about'},
]

class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            activeMenu: 0,
        }       
    }

    handleClick(i) {
        this.setState({
            activeMenu: i 
        })
    }

    renderMenuButton(i) {
        let className = "button"
        
        if (this.state.activeMenu == i) {
            className = "active-menu"
        } 
                
        return (
            <MenuButton 
                key = {menus[i].id}
                name = {menus[i].name}
                route = {menus[i].route}
                id = {menus[i].id}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
                className = {className}
            />
        );
    }
    
    renderSwitch(i) {
        return (
            <Route path = {menus[i].route} key = {menus[i].id}>
                {'<' + menus[i].route + ' />'}
            </Route>
        );
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="container-menu-main">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Admin menu</li>
                        <li onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}>WORKING!!!</li>
                        {menus.map((menu) => this.renderMenuButton(menu.id))} {/* DOES NOT WORK */}
                    </ul>
                    <Switch>
                        {menus.map((menu) => this.renderSwitch(menu.id))}
                    </Switch>                   
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
    
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Providing a running sample would really help I guess.

Comment: You could check it with different mobile browsers. It might be a browser related issue.

Comment: I checked with Chrome and Mi browser.

Comment: Running sample: https://master.dcl8mxikpvkz.amplifyapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there is the problem width the CSS. On mobiles devices, the active color will be the :hover color, and if I remove the hover color or set the same as the active color, it's working fine. I don't know why and I'm not happy with it, because I don't understand.

In the other hand, I realized, that there is a built-in solution for active link in  react router, so I don't need to manage myself.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `menu.id` to `this.renderMenuButton`, but it looks like `this.renderMenuButton` expects an index. Can you try this:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './menu-main.sass';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
}   from "react-router-dom";

const MenuButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <li className={props.className} onClick={props.onClick}>
            <Link to={'/' + props.route}>{props.name}</Link>
        </li>
    );
}

const menus = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Products', route: 'products'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Categories', route: 'category'},
    {id: 2, name: 'About', route: 'about'},
]

class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            activeMenu: 0,
        }       
    }

    handleClick(i) {
        this.setState({
            activeMenu: i 
        })
    }

    renderMenuButton(i) {
        let className = "button"
        
        if (this.state.activeMenu == i) {
            className = "active-menu"
        } 
                
        return (
            <MenuButton 
                key = {menus[i].id}
                name = {menus[i].name}
                route = {menus[i].route}
                id = {menus[i].id}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
                className = {className}
            />
        );
    }
    
    renderSwitch(i) {
        return (
            <Route path = {menus[i].route} key = {menus[i].id}>
                {'<' + menus[i].route + ' />'}
            </Route>
        );
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="container-menu-main">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Admin menu</li>
                        <li onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}>WORKING!!!</li>
                        {menus.map((menu, i) => this.renderMenuButton(i))} {/* Pass index instead of menu.id */}
                    </ul>
                    <Switch>
                        {menus.map((menu) => this.renderSwitch(menu.id))}
                    </Switch>                   
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
    
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunatelly it still doesn't work.